# "Making a Murderer" fans had better get their boots on

Tags: meaning, expressions

> "Making a Murderer" fans **had better get their boots on**.

<sup>([Source: Steven Avery's lawyer promises evidence 'tsunami'](http://www.greenbaypressgazette.com/story/news/2016/07/08/steven-averys-lawyer-promises-evidence-tsunami/86827694/))</sup>

Can you explain to me what fans should do in the above sentence? I presume that "get their boots on" is used in the figurative sense, and given the context I would say that it means something to that effect that the fans should spring their attention but not sure.

Comment: *Please* give us some context. How are we supposed to tell you what the answer is if we don't know where this text originates? Link to where you saw it, include more of the quote... something, anything... one sentence alone tells us nothing.

Comment: My guess is it's a mangling of [*better get their/his/her/my **skates** on*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22better+get+my+skates+on%22) *(they should / it would be better if they **got a move on**)*.

Comment: In the UK we used to have [bovver boys](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bovver_boy), who [looked like this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22bovver+boys%22&biw=1575&bih=821&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7qb3pjuXNAhVSOMAKHabEAMwQ7AkIKg&dpr=1) (note the big boots, for stoving people's heads in). Maybe the idea is that fans of "Making a Murderer" (who presumably mostly think Avery was framed by corrupt lawmen) can finally get ready to give those corrupt lawmen a good kicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the phrase

> get on your boots

can mean several different things, my guess is that given the context of *Making a Murderer* with its convoluted plots and evidence, the meaning of

> *Making a Murderer* fans **had better** get their boots on.

means the fans should be ready for the plot of the series to get *deep, muddy, and murky*

[image: here]


It does not have the same meaning implied by U2 in their song *Get On Your Boots*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the context of "making a murderer", but [get your boots on](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=put%20my%20boots%20on) is prison slang for preparing for a riot or a fight.

Comment: *Making a murderer* is a Netflix  "television"  series.